# How to wait for long times?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wait

I'm making a discord.py bot and I would like to implement a reminder command. I have an issue, though: If the bot goes down, I don't want to lose all my asyncio.wait() times. How could I make the times carry over (with a database)? I also would rather not query the database 60 times per minute and check, whether it has passed that time for **every** document. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: you can serialize to db, but also have your bot remember the wait times. Serialize to db with a UUID that the bot's function knows, then when the function runs as part of its teardown it deletes the row from the db. When the bot starts as part of its init it should go look at each entry in the reminder table and set up those async calls to run on time.

Comment: Is it practical to run many asyncio.wait()s at once? Will it slow down the bot to have so many tasks running simultaneously?

Comment: `asyncio.wait` is literally no task, so no -- you should be able to spin millions of those tasks with no effect on performance. `asyncio.wait` just tells the task scheduler to delay execution of a thing.

Comment: You probably want the database to be a “write-through cache” for a dict or other structure that you store in memory, so the only time you need to query it is at startup. You may be able to get that out of the box by using the `shelve` module in the stdlib, if you don’t need a more powerful database than “pickles in a dbm”.